# Dependabot at git branch

Tags: git, github, branch

I have created a repository and some branch to it. But a branch named dependabot is created automatically. Is it a good practice to keep dependabot branch on a repository ?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/marketplace/dependabot-preview) is what a dependabot does. If it's your personal repo you can choose to remove it. If not ask the team to.

Comment: The link is broken, would you please fix it?

Comment: @AHMADEZZAT Here is the ["Dependabot Preview " App](https://web.archive.org/web/20191102060211/https://github.com/marketplace/dependabot-preview) link restored, but it is no longer required, since it is integrated with GitHub Actions. See [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58742648/6309).

Answer (score 0):

Nov. 2019: You can delete it, but since [GitHub has acquired Dependabot](https://web.archive.org/web/20191225213725/https://dependabot.com/blog/hello-github/), it is possible it is activated on any public repository for [project with the right language](https://web.archive.org/web/20191226230250/https://dependabot.com/#languages).

So the next scan might recreate that branch anyway.
You can [configure the scan if you want](https://web.archive.org/web/20191217222529/https://dependabot.com/docs/config-file/).

---

2022: Dependabot is fully [integrated as GitHub Actions](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-10-06-github-actions-workflows-triggered-by-dependabot-prs-will-respect-permissions-key-in-workflows/) (or [webhooks](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-06-new-dependabot-alerts-webhook/)), and had [many evolutions](https://github.blog/changelog/label/dependabot/) over the past three years.
No more "`dependabot`" branch needed.

Comment: The link is broken, would you please fix it?

Comment: @AHMADEZZAT Thank you for the feedback. I have restored the links, and updated the answer accordingly.